# Function returns zero how can fix this?

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, append

I want to create a dynamical appen method, but the parameter is not properly reflected in the function. Reflected color value zero

```js
$(document).ready(function(colorr) {
  $("button").click(function(colorr) {
    $("body").append(function(colorr) {
      return "<div style='border:1px solid black;border-color: red;  width: 60px;height: 60px;'> " + colorr + " item </div>";
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button id="button" data-value1="yellow">Append list item</button></td>
      <button onclick="button('yellow')">Try it</button></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: maybe it would be useful to someone who did this way                                                                                                              <tr><td collspan="2"><button onclick="metod()">do it</button></td></tr>                                                                                                function metod(){$("body").append('<div style="border: 2px solid '+bcolor+'; float: left; width: '+width+'px;height: '+height+'px;">' + i + '.div  <br> '+height+'X'+width+'</div>');}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you cannot pass arguments to jQuery event handlers in the manner you're attempting.

You instead need to read the `data` attribute from the element using the `this` reference within the `click` handler. Then you can build a HTML string which you concatenate that value to and provide it to an `append()` method call. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var colorr = $(this).data('value1');
    $("body").append('<div>' + colorr + ' item</div>');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: red;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <button data-value1="yellow">Append list item</button>
      <button data-value1="red">Append list item</button>
      <button data-value1="blue">Append list item</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```